# TimelineJS3 how paste date to the popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline.js

how  i can  move post date to the popup ?

please see image [iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OivY.jpg)

I was trying this code `

```
    this._el.text                   = TL.Dom.create("div", "tl-timemarker-text", this._el.content);
    this._text                      = TL.Dom.create("h2", "tl-headline", this._el.text);
    this._el.date               = TL.Dom.create("h3", "tl-headline-date", this._el.text);
    this._el.date               =  TL.Util.unlinkify(this.data.date);`
```

but it stillnot work

Answer (score -3):

> You can use the following jquery horizontal timeline.js library. It is easy to use and you can customize it. I think it will help you: https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html